AWS Lambda supports nodejs20.x but @serverless-stack package is still on node 16
I have decided to update the modules of our Next.js(ts) aws appsync, aws lambda, nodejs, aws conginito, mondodb, SST app. To nodejs20.x
I found out that AWS Lambda supports nodejs20.x but @serverless-stack in it's latest version (1.18.4) is still on node 16 (the app needs @serverless-stack for running). as it's tsconfig says:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Should I remain on the version that our modules understand or is there any possible solution?( I already checked the entire web, adjusting the package code but it has it's risk, it will not run once deployed since it will get the official version)

What have you tried so far? What makes you think there's a problem? What happens if you just try it?

I just trick ts  runtime: 'nodejs20.x' as'nodejs14.x', it work on dev. but on prod  not for a long time.. since aws will  support nodejs14 until April2026. It's like a countdown until the app crashes
